# Is it possible to "advance" a mutable slice through a mutable reference?

Tags: rust, slice

I often do things like this with shared slices:

```rust
fn read_a_few_bytes(slice: &mut &[u8]) {
    dbg!(&slice[..3]);
    *slice = &slice[3..];
}
```

Today I noticed that that approach doesn't work when the slice is mutable:

```rust
fn read_a_few_bytes(slice: &mut &mut [u8]) {
    dbg!(&slice[..3]);
    *slice = &mut slice[3..];
}
```

The second example gives this error:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:3:5
  |
1 | fn read_a_few_bytes(slice: &mut &mut [u8]) {
  |                            -    - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'2`
  |                            |
  |                            let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
2 |     dbg!(&slice[..3]);
3 |     *slice = &mut slice[3..];
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ assignment requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
```

Is this a borrow checker limitation, or is there some way that what I'm trying to do here is actually unsound? Is there a workaround?

Comment: You can't have more than one mutable reference to same thing anyway. Also the double mut pointer is a classic problem in C (well in C it's for const but anyway same thing). So no you can't do this in rust.

Comment: The suggestion from rustc 1.69 suggested change to the signature `fn read_a_few_bytes<'a>(slice: &'a mut &'a mut [u8]) {`, and this additional lifetime parameter `'a` nails them all down to prevent the lifetime mismatch, is that what you might want?

Comment: Maybe it's worth writing out the expression using fully qualified syntax to get a clearer idea of what's going on? Admittedly I tried it and was still confused. Maybe you can see something that I can't. Btw love your firehose of Rust video; huge fan.

Comment: @metatoaster it's compile but I don't know if in practice it's very useful. I didn't except rust to accept this. Alternative `fn read_a_few_bytes<'a, 'b: 'a>(slice: &'b mut &'a mut [u8])`

Comment: @metatoaster if you follow the compiler's suggestion you get a function that works one time, but then it keeps the slice permanently borrowed, and you can't call it again. The same thing happens if you use two lifetime parameters.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that context on why that suggestion isn't that useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [std::mem::take](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.take.html) to solve this.

```
fn read_a_few_bytes(slice: &mut &mut [u8]) {
    let data = std::mem::take(slice);
    *slice = &mut data[3..];
}
```

Comment: For reference, this is what the unstable `take*_mut` functions do https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/slice/mod.rs.html#4091

Comment: Thank you! It's remarkable that you can construct an empty `&mut [T]` for any `T` and any lifetime and just swap it in.